# mysql - "column cannot be null"

Tags: mysql, null

as you see in the title, even if i removed "not null" feature from the related field, it still doesn't let me to insert null value for that field although the field is nullable!

Any help would be appreciated.

EDITED

## Create:

```
CREATE TABLE `review` (
..
`RATING` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
..
(`CATALOG_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31625 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin5 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

## Query:

```
INSERT INTO review (RATING,..) VALUES (null,..);
```

## Error message:

```
Error: Column 'RATING' cannot be null
SQLState:  23000
ErrorCode: 1048
```

I also try to insert without RATING in the insert query, even if it is default null and nullable field, it gives the same error message and never inserts the field.

Comment: *Teh codes* please. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and post it here.

Comment: I have edited content of the question, thanks.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: Any triggers on the table? Execute this: show triggers like 'review'; What about constraints? Execute this too: show create table review; and paste result into question.

Comment: Bohemian, thanks for your attention. You are right, i figured out that there is a trigger for insert action which effects the related field. I am going to talk the responsible developer soon and try to remove or update the trigger in order to get over of that problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Bohemian, pls write down your post again as an answer so i can mark it as the correct one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bohemian, thanks for your attention. You are right, I figured out that there is a trigger for insert action which effects the related field. I disabled the trigger and the error is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: It helped me too :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all look your "datetime / created_at / updated_at" field, do not assign the default value, select current time. after that you can can update the fields name