# Column cannot be null mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a similar error as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248983/mysql-column-cannot-be-null). I get a NULL field error even though i've passed the value with insert command. Here is the sql export of my tables, trigger and procedure:

```
--TRIGGER
CREATE TRIGGER `ubaci_nagradu`
AFTER INSERT ON `Dokumenti`
FOR EACH ROW CALL generiraj_nagradu(NEW.k_fk)


--INSERT COMMAND
INSERT INTO `Dokumenti` (`d_putanja`, `d_naziv`, `d_opis`, `k_fk`, `d_mime`, `d_ime`) VALUES ('/home/path/uploads/', 'TTTT', 'TTTTTTTTTTTTT', '1', 'application/pdf', 'diplomski-prezantacija1376329220.pdf')

--PROCEDURE
CREATE DEFINER=`studentx`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `generiraj_nagradu`(IN `korisnik_id` INT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN  
    DECLARE ID INT(11);
    DECLARE OPIS VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE BROJ INT(11);
    SELECT n_id INTO @ID FROM Nagrade;
    SELECT n_opis INTO @OPIS FROM Nagrade;
    SELECT n_broj INTO @BROJ FROM Nagrade;
    IF (@BROJ > 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO KorisnikNagrada VALUES (NULL, korisnik_id, @ID, NOW());
        INSERT INTO Notifikacije VALUES (NULL, @korisnik_id, "Dobili ste nagradu: " + @OPIS, 0);
        SET BROJ = BROJ - 1;
        UPDATE Nagrade SET n_broj = @BROJ WHERE n_id = @ID;
    END IF;
END

--TABLES
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Dokumenti` (
    `d_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `d_naziv` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `d_opis` tinytext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,      
    `d_putanja` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,      
    `k_fk` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `d_mime` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,      
    `d_ime` varchar(250) NOT NULL,      
    PRIMARY KEY (`d_id`),
    KEY `dokumenti_korisnici_idx` (`k_fk`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB  
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=19;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `KorisnikNagrada` (
  `kn_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `k_fk` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `n_fk` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `kn_vrijeme` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kn_id`),
  KEY `k_fk` (`k_fk`),
  KEY `n_fk` (`n_fk`),
  KEY `k_fk_2` (`k_fk`),
  KEY `n_fk_2` (`n_fk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Notifikacije` (
  `nt_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `k_fk` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nt_poruka` tinytext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nt_vidjeo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nt_id`),
  KEY `k_fk` (`k_fk`),
  KEY `k_fk_2` (`k_fk`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Any help is appreciated :-)
Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Which column is null?  And what line was generating the error?

Comment: Its giving me an error when I try to insert new record that k_fk field is null, as you can see from INSERT statement it's not null it's 1. So probably i'm missing on something in trigger declaration.

Comment: Is there a k_fk column in KorisnikNagrada or Notifikacije?  More than likely it's in the trigger.

Comment: Yup there is, updated the post with tbles needed :-)

Comment: I don't get errors with this (with exactly 1 row in nagrade, which I assume is your intent).  Perhaps you're getting `NULL` from Nagrade and failing putting it into KorisnikNagrada in the trigger?

Comment: The problem was with the parameter that I passed korisnik_id i have put @korisnik_id (in procedure while inserting into Notifikacije) which is not declared in this scope so is NULL. Your suggestion is spot on thanks man for directing me in right direction :-)